# When I start a gateway projcet , nothing happned in my pc ,but it failed launch in k8s pod , any one can help me?

Tags: java, spring

## **(not good at english , forgive me for  any text grammar/word mistake)**

**The excption is**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class \[org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.propagation.SleuthTagPropagationAutoConfiguration$TagPropagationConfiguration\] from ClassLoader \[org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@51684e4a\]
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358)
at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742)
at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:741)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:680)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:648)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1614)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:495)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:620)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1243)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:890)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:878)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:865)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:803)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236)
at com.hulk.service.gateway.teacher.HulkTeacherGatewayApplication.main(HulkTeacherGatewayApplication.java:13)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
Location:
org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/propagation/SleuthTagPropagationAutoConfiguration$TagPropagationConfiguration.tagPropagationSpanHandler(Lorg/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/SleuthProperties;Lorg/springframework/cloud/sleuth/propagation/SleuthTagPropagationProperties;)Lbrave/handler/SpanHandler; @9: areturn
Reason:
Type 'org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/propagation/TagPropagationFinishedSpanHandler' (current frame, stack\[0\]) is not assignable to 'brave/handler/SpanHandler' (from method signature)
Current Frame:
bci: @9
flags: { }
locals: { 'org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/autoconfig/SleuthProperties', 'org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/propagation/SleuthTagPropagationProperties' }
stack: { 'org/springframework/cloud/sleuth/propagation/TagPropagationFinishedSpanHandler' }
Bytecode:
0x0000000: bb00 0259 2a2b b700 03b0

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463)
    ... 29 common frames omitted
```

**Here is some my project libs' version:
**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6ZHD.png)

First I think it's vresion problem ,but i have a other gateway project what's lib's version are same is launched . now i have idea what should i do ;

i try search in goolgle to find same error msg, no one else

Comment: could you give us more info?for example your configuration class or spring boot application class,it says you mistake in a method return type

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the project is pure spring boot project which only hava one class  ; Here is the code. ```public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }```

Comment: thank all . The problem has been solved. the problem's reason is the skyworking agent version incompatible